# Try to upload files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload multiple files which in Laravel but not able to do so..

my php code ( All the session values are there.

session('prescriptionFiles') has the tmp_name values.
session('prescriptionFilesName') has the file names

```
public function selectAddress()
    {
        $prescriptions = session('prescriptionFiles');
        $prescriptionsFileNames = session('prescriptionFilesName');
        $userId = Input::get('userId');


        for($i=0; $i<count($prescriptions); $i++){
           move_uploaded_file($prescriptions[$i], "files/$prescriptionsFileNames[$i]");
        }
    }
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Comment: the issue is I dont have direct access the uploaded files and I have to pass the data through sessions so don't know how to get this to work